# What is wrong with my array append function?

Tags: php

```
$allAmazonMatches = Array ( [1] => B002I0HJZO [2] => B002I0HJzz [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc )
```

I am doing:

```
array_push($allAmazonMatches, array("0"=>"None of the products match"));
```

How ever, I am unable to add the additional array to $allAmazonMatches?

Comment: what do you mean by "adding additional array" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will work fine, so im assuming youre trying to input that text into index `0` of the array. There you should do...

```
$allAmazonMatches[0] = "None of the products match";
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `array_push` you'll get:

```
Array(
    [1] => B002I0HJZO
    [2] => B002I0HJzz
    [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc
    [4] => Array(
        [0] => None of the products match
    )
)
```

I guess, this is not what you want but you are looking for:

```
Array(
    [1] => B002I0HJZO
    [2] => B002I0HJzz
    [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc
    [4] => None of the products match
)
```

Then you have to use:

```
array_merge($allAmazonMatches, array("0"=>"None of the products match"));
```

Comment: I did that but nothing happened

Comment: What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: Array(
    [1] => B002I0HJZO
    [2] => B002I0HJzz
    [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc
    [4] => Array(
        [0] => None of the products match
    )
)

Comment: that is what happened....I just wanted to add another key. Anyways I figured it out. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use array push with just one element. Here's what you're looking to do, along with three variations in the [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jRSr9V):

```
$allAmazonMatches = array( 1 => "B002I0HJZO", 2 => "B002I0HJzz", 3 => "B002I0HJccccccccc");
$allAmazonMatches[] = "None of the products match";
var_dump( $allAmazonMatches);
```